# Elasticsearch aggregation with custom query parser

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I cannot seem to aggregate my query results when using my custom query parser. I get a result set by these are not aggregated. When using a standard query parser like match everything turns out well.

What works:

```
GET pages/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text": "binomial"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "docs": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "rooturl"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

returns a nice aggregated result:

```
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 10,
    "max_score": 11.11176,
    "hits": [
    ...
      {
        "_index": "pages",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "AVcq6z6lzDazctHi91RE",
        "_score": 3.3503218,
        "_source": {
          "rooturl": "document",
          "type": "equation",
          "url": "document:poly",
          "text": "coefficient"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "pages",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "AVcq6z6xzDazctHi91RF",
        "_score": 3.3503218,
        "_source": {
          "rooturl": document",
          "type": "equation",
          "url": "document:poly",
          "text": "dot"
        }
      }
    ...
    ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "docs": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "document",
          "doc_count": 10
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But when using my custom query parser, The result is not aggregated.

Query:

```
GET pages/_search
{
  "query": {
    "my_custom_query_parser": {
      "query": "binomial"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "docs": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "rooturl"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone point me into the right direction?

Comment: `my_custom_query_parser` is not a valid ES query. Where does it come from?

Comment: I created an ES plugin with a custom query parser. The parser takes the input from the "query" field, transforms it and sends out a Lucene query to ES. ES successfully searches and returns a response; similar to match.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code of your custom query parser that will help us to know the issue?